# Can a call to write(2) be interrupted by OS with an fsync(2)

Tags: system-calls, fsync

I have a loop of write(2) with arbitrary amount of data + EOL and an fsync(2) appending to a file line by line.

Can a crash of the process leave me with a file that has half of the data from the write(2) call written to file?
My theory is that if the OS calls fsync occasionally, there might be a coincidence of it happening during a call the write(2) leaving the file with half of the line written, without the ending new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Even without a crash, you might have a partial line written as the `write` call might not write all the data passed to it -- it might return a short write.

Comment: How come there aren't more examples online that deal with this sort of file append corruption? Presumably the reason we have so many file database projects is to ensure file corruption doesn't happen?